# Flash of white screen before page & iframe loads

Tags: javascript, html, css

Is it possible to avoid having the white screen when a page loads? Particularly for the iframes i'm using on my page? it looks odd having a box of white on the screen while the parent contents are themed already.

Thanks in advance!! :)

Comment: possible duplicate of [iframe flashes "white" on load](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2351232/iframe-flashes-white-on-load)

Answer (score 2):

Have you tried setting the background color of the iframe to the background color of your parent page?

Comment: i didn't set any background to the iframe..should i do that? cause it'll probably only affect the way it shows when the frame already loads. my iframe's background now is transparent so the contents of the frame are lying on top of the parent page's themes. you can check out the site: giroapps.com

Thanks!! :)

Answer (score 0):

If the iframes are on the same domain, you could use JavaScript to set `style.visibility= 'hidden'` on the iframes from the parent document, then have the child documents reach up into the parent document and call a function to set `visibility` back to `visible` when they're loaded enough to have a stylesheet with the correct background. (`onload` on the child frame, or potentially sooner.)

I don't know that it's worth it, really. People are used to incomplete rendering whilst a page loads.

Comment: yup..the iframes are on the same domain..how do i do this exactly? :)

thanks in advance!!

Comment: Well, in the simplest case you could have `<iframe id="fooframe" src="child.html" style="visibility: hidden">` in the parent document, and in the child document say `<script type="text/javascript">window.onload= function() { window.parent.getElementById('fooframe').style.visibility= 'visible'; };</script>`. However it would be better to make the hiddenness happen only when JavaScript was enabled, else the iframe will never appear on browsers where JS is unavailable. And also you might want to enable visibility again sooner than `onload` if the child document has a lot of image content.

Answer (score 0):

You could make the iframe invisible until it loads.

Making it invisible with the following `iframe.style.visibility='hidden';` will make your iframe hidden but it will still occupy the space it used to have

And when it loads simply make it visible again with `iframe.style.visibility='visible';` and you won't see any flashing..

Clean and simple imo.