# iframe flashes "white" on load

Tags: jquery, events, iframe, background

I am using an iframe in my project and it seems that whenever it loads content on a opacity background - it flashes "white" for around 1 second before correctly appearing.

It seems that it fires loaded event before the jQuery script is ready. I have tried

```
style="visibility:hidden;" onload="this.style.visibility = 'visible';"
```

but doesn't work. Any other ideas to get rid of this ?

Comment: Here I find another good solution that is working:
http://swsharinginfo.blogspot.com/2011/11/avoid-iframe-white-flash-issue-while.html

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Try using:

```
style="display:none" onload="this.style.display = 'block';"
```

`visibility:hidden` doesn't actually "hide" the element as such - it still takes up the space it would if it were visible. `display:none` actually makes the element completely invisible, as if it doesn't exist.

Comment: No problem. I had a similar issue when I first learned about `visibility: hidden`. :)

Answer (score 4):

If you have control over the framed page - Set your background color on that page to transparent. Most browsers are white by default

Answer (score 0):

I had some difficulty with getting:

`style="display:none" onload="this.style.display = 'block';"`

to work in my situation on Chrome and Safari.

If these aren't working for you, try:

`style="opacity: 0;" onload="this.style.opacity = 1;"`

Answer (score 0):

I had exactly this problem, and tried all the remedies on this page without success.  It was flashing on Chrome, not FireFox.

What worked for me was changing:

```
$("#iframe").prop('src', url);
```

to

```
$("#iframe").attr('href', url);
```

Answer (score 0):

I found that inline styling the element works best.

```
<iframe style="background:black;" 
   height="100%" width="100%" scrolling="no">
</iframe>
```

I needed to have this style change based on a user's dark mode preference, so I used parameterization with calculated CSS variables.

CSS

```
:root
{ 
   --is-dark-mode: 0;
   --background-color-hue: 0; 
   --background-color-saturation: 0%; 
   --background-color-lightness: calc((100 - (var(--is-dark-mode) * 100)) * 1%); 
   --background-color: hsl(var(--background-color-hue), 
       var(--background-color-saturation), 
       var(--background-color-lightness)); 
}
```

HTML

```
<iframe style="background:var(--background-color);" 
   height="100%" width="100%" scrolling="no">
</iframe>
```